# Disable text once it is moved from one UL to another UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

This code will add the items from the list on right to left when clicked. We have to click on the pop up image to move. Now what i was expected to do is to get the elements from a json file and once i had moved an text to the other box it must that selection must be disabled. user must not be able to click it again, which in another word one item can be selected once. But that item MUST not be removed from the first list. Please help. thanks in advance

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery_ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            #firstlist li:hover img {display: inline;}
            #firstlist li:hover { background: #CCF5CC; }
            #firstlist .ui-selected { background: #80B280; }
            #firstlist { list-style-type: none;}
            #firstlist li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.3em;}

            #seclist {list-style-type: none;}
            #seclist li {padding: 0.2em;}

            img {display:none;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="myTable" class= "table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-6 text-center success">
                    List 1
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-6 text-center success">
                    List 2
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td class="col-md-6">
                    <ul id="firstlist">
                        <li>Apple <img src="next.jpg" id="next1"></li>
                        <li>Orange <img src="next.jpg" id="next2"></li>
                        <li>Avacado <img src="next.jpg" id="next3"></li>
                        <li>Banana <img src="next.jpg" id="next4"></li>
                        <li>Mango <img src="next.jpg" id="next5"></li>
                    <ul>    
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class = "seclist" id = "seclist"> </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script>        
            $(function(){
                $( "#firstlist" ).selectable();
            });

            $(function() {
                $( "#seclist" ).selectable();
            });

            $("img").click(function() {
                var text = $(this).closest("li").text();
                $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.seclist')
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you know the text is disabled

Comment: please share jsfiddle link

Comment: actually it doesnt have to be disabled. The user must not be able to add again. So it will be ok if the image is disabled or even if its visible when hovered the move must not happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/vcUfR/1/)

Check the above link. Just unbind the click event

```
     $("img").click(function(event) {
            var text = $(this).closest("li").text();
            $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.seclist');
            $(this).unbind('click');
        });
```

It ll not remove the element and lets you click it only first time.

Comment: +1 It is good solution. you can use `$(this).unbind('click')` instead of `$(event.target).parent().find('img').unbind('click')` and remove unnecessary parenthesis [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/vcUfR/4/)

Comment: Yeah:) Thanks for your suggestion. Modified to shorter efficient version

Comment: thanks alot. It works. So in case if i want to enable it again from any other function what should i do. For example if i wanted to remove the items from the second list by clicking on the image(which i have to add) and enable it back for addition what should i do??? Thanks again for replying

Comment: Do bind('click',function(){})

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("img").on("click" , function() {
            var text1 = $(this).closest("li").text();
            $('ul.seclist').append("<li>"+text1+"</li>");
            $(this).off("click");
});
```

or

```
$("img").on("click" , function() {
            var text1 = $(this).closest("li").text();
            $('<li />', {html: text1}).appendTo('ul.seclist');
            $(this).off("click");
   });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcUfR/3/)

Comment: what is the difference between your code and OP's? I am not able to get it.

Comment: thanks alot. It works. So in case if i want to enable it again from any other function what should i do. For example if i wanted to remove the items from the second list by clicking on the image(which i have to add) and enable it back for addition what should i do??? Thanks again for replying